# What does collation utf8mb4_unicode_ci mean

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, collation

I was working on a project and wanted to implement a posts table similar to the wordpress posts table to store page content.

So I basically copied the wp_posts table which is longtext however I noticed under collation it had utf8mb4_unicode_ci

I'm wondering what this means and what its necessary for?

Comment: Is your question about _character sets_ utf8mb4 vs utf8?  Or about _unicode_ci versus other _collations_?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL collation: utf8mb4\_unicode\_ci vs "utf8mb4 - default collation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51278467/mysql-collation-utf8mb4-unicode-ci-vs-utf8mb4-default-collation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`utf8mb4_unicode_ci` support full unicode in mysql databases.

More information can be found here https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

Basically there are many characters in Unicode that cant be stored in table with utf8, thus resulting in data loss.

UTF-8 symbols take one to three bytes, but there are symbols that can take even 4, and these werent supported (`utf8` - `utf8mb4`).

In wordpress this change from utf8 collation was cause of problems for some users, mostly because `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` is supported only in MySQL 5.5.3+.