# MySQL collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci vs "utf8mb4 - default collation"

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, collation

Please help me to understand the differences between the collations listed in MySQL Workbench:

`utf8mb4_unicode_ci` vs `utf8mb4 - default collation`

p.s. Everyone is recommending using `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`. If this is so popular why it is not default? What differs it from the default?

I use MySQL 5.7.21.

[image: MySQL Workbench]

Comment: Do `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to discover what the "default" really is.  I think it will say `utf8mb4_general_ci` or maybe `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`.  Furthermore, the default probably changes with the version of MySQL.

Answer (score 34):

`utf8mb4_default`??  Where do you see this?

The default collation (before MySQL 8.0) for utf8mb4 is `utf8mb4_general_ci`.  This checks only one byte at a time, so `ss` is not considered equal to `ß`.  Most of the other collations for utf8mb4 do consider them equal.

Next in the list of "better" collations for general use (as opposed to Spanish-specific, etc) is `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.  This matches the Unicode Collation Algorithm version 4.0, written several years ago.

Then comes `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` (Unicode 5.20), which handles more things "correctly".

When you get to MySQL 8.0, there will be a 9.0 version, `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`.

For details on the differences, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html . (Note: "utf8" versus "utf8mb4" work the same for the information provided on that page.)  The first thing to note:

```
utf8_general_ci         A=a=À=Á=Â=Ã=Ä=Å=à=á=â=ã=ä=å=Ā=ā=Ą=ą    Aa  ae          az
utf8_unicode_ci       A=a=ª=À=Á=Â=Ã=Ä=Å=à=á=â=ã=ä=å=Ā=ā=Ą=ą  Aa  ae          az            Æ=æ
utf8_unicode_520_ci   A=a=ª=À=Á=Â=Ã=Ä=Å=à=á=â=ã=ä=å=Ā=ā=Ą=ą  Aa  ae=Æ=æ      az
```

These 3 lines point out 3 different treatments of `Æ` and `æ`.

- Those two ligatures are treated equal ("case insensitive").
- *general* does not sort it anywhere near the other A's.  (Far below, we see that they sort after `Z`.)
- *unicode* sorts them after all A's, and just before B, as if they were a separate "letter".
- *unicode_520* treats them as equal to letter pair `ae`.

For 5.7, and without any specific language requirements, I would use `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`.

Back to your question of "why".  Changing defaults runs the risk of hurting existing installations more than it helps.  So, I guess, the designers were conservative.  On the other hand, 8.0 has a lot of major changes, so there was less reluctance to change.  Hence, the move to utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci.

Comment: Thank you for answer, please have a look at the image I attached to the question.

Comment: I don't have `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`. I have only `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`  and `utf8mb4_default` - and I cannot find any description about what is the `default` in context of `utf8mb4_default`. Thank you.

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev - Now that I see the image, I would say that it is a sloppy list.  It's not saying `utf8mb4_default`, it is saying `utf8mb4` - "default" collation, which is a dumb thing to say since it gives you no clue which one is the default.  And I think there are errors in the list.  File a bug report against Workbench at bugs.mysql.com

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev - Meanwhile, pick `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`; it will probably be the best available.

Comment: Thank you. So my question was reasonable, it is not only me see "no clue which one is the default". Thank you.

Comment: Strange - I'm pretty sure `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` came into existence with 5.6.0; you are running 5.7.21.

Comment: `SHOW COLLATION LIKE 'utf8mb4%';`